# Shipping Methods Issue

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

We have setup the shipping option on our site at southernrecords.co.uk but when we progress an order through to the checkout page we are getting a red cross and highlighted area by the shipping. Also the method text (Flat Rate) isn't being displayed.

Would you have any idea why this should happen?
You can check it by going to southernrecords.co.uk - adding an item to the cart - then clicking the cart icon top right and selecting proceed to checkout - scroll to the bottom to see the problem.

we are new to Magento2 so any help would really be appreciated

Thanks
Rich
[image: Shipping Error]

Answer (score 0):

### Having spent several hours looking for a solution I eventually spoke to my ISP on their chat and within 5 minutes he solved the problem.

### Veselin B.: In regards to your issue with Magento today, since version 2, Magento included dynamic versioning of the templates and the changes done to the website, the add a prefix called "versionXXX" where XXX can be any number of any length, and it's being read as a folder. There was an .htaccess file in the pub/static/ folder which had the wrong permissions and this versioning thing was not read properly, thus it generated hundreds of errors

He corrected this for me andnot only did the website perform much better it also solved the problems on the shipping page we were having.
Hope this might help someone in the future
Cheers
Rich